# Is the complex function $f(z) = \sec z$ analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Please help.
Is $f(z) = \sec(z)$ analytic?

I do know that I have to test if the cauchy riemann equations hold. That is
$U_x = V_y$ and $U_y = -V_x$

But I have trouble expressing $f(z)$ in the form
$f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$

Comment: It is analytic at alll points where $\cos z \neq 0$, i.e all points except $\frac {(2n+1)\pi} 2, n\in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: You don't need the CR-equations here. Quotients of analytic functions are analytic.

Comment: Thanks Vercassivelaunos